# teamcity with svn not working

Tags: svn, teamcity

It just runs forever and this is all the log shows:

```
[11:38:08]: Checking for changes
[11:38:10]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[11:38:11]: Checkout directory: C:\SVN\files
[11:38:11]: Updating sources: agent side checkout...
[11:38:11]: [Updating sources: agent side checkout...] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Agent doesn't have any version of the project sources
[11:38:11]: [Updating sources: agent side checkout...] Cleaning C:\SVN\files
[11:38:11]: [Updating sources: agent side checkout...] VCS Root: cust svn files
[11:38:11]: [VCS Root: cust svn files] revision: 30050_2011/06/02 11:32:49 -0700
[11:38:11]: [VCS Root: cust svn files] Will use fast SVN
```

I have tried the `'clean' options` - I have restarted the server and tried several times and this is all I get - it just runs all night long and never does anything. I have also checked the `'test'` for SVN root which works fine.

I have used TeamCity with Vault but not SVN so I'm sure I just have something wrong.

Also this is running on Windows 2008 R2 Standard -- I also have the build agent running under the admin account..

---

Resolved - the path to my repository was incorrect.  I never got an error, it was just hanging.  Everything is working now.  TeamCity really needs better docs/walkthrougs etc.

Comment: can you post the VCS setting and checkout rules, if those are not right u mite be having some network issues possibly

Comment: does it check out anything at all like any partial files? Have you tried checking-out the VCS defined URL out manually?

Comment: thanks guys, the issue was i didnt have the repository path correct - but it never gave an error or anything - would just hang

Answer (score 2):

This actually happened to me today. I removed the previously created work folder and ran the build again, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Happened today for me, TC version 9.1.6.

Had to:

1. Delete the work directory on agent
2. Empty the VCS root folder in %ProgramData%\JetBrains\TeamCity\system/caches/git. (You would need to look into the map file to figure out which folder to empty)
3. Remove the VCS root entry from the map file.

Seems to have started to work now. It is possible that only one of the above steps was enough. But I don't know which one (if any).